# MUI TreeItem closing when select other TreeItem

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, treeview, mui-x

I need help with my treeview.
I do a classic treeview with children who also have children.
I created a constant to update certain values depending on where the user clicks.
So I added an 'onClick' on my TreeItem with a console.log to display my different values, so far no problems. But the moment I want to Set a value my Treeview no longer has the same behavior at all.
As soon as I select another TreeItem this will have the effect of cutting the Toogle.

I use event.stopPropagation() but nothing change.

I tried onNoSelect on the TreeView and i have the same result

example:

```
  const action = (event: SyntheticEvent, nodeId: number) => {
    console.log('nodeId: ', nodeId);
    setIdClientState(nodeId); // When i had this i have my problem, And when I remove it, no more problems
  };
```

thank you !

Comment: Please share a reproduction of your code (CodeSandbox, GH repo). What version of the Tree View component are you using? Is it the current MUI X version, or an older Material UI Lab version?